# query issue with a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

*Requirement* : Get the All  users in the **Login** Table + and their *LATEST* Login Record  from   **UserLogin** Table for provided tenant

*Current Query* :

```
SELECT [USER].UserName , UserLogin.AttemptDate , UserLogin.LogoutDate
FROM [User] LEFT JOIN UserLogin 
ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
WHERE  [User].TenantId=3 
ORDER BY UserLogin.LogoutDate desc
```

*Issue :* Repeats the User Name not Distinct

Comment: Don't know much of sql-azure, just mysql, but have you tried `GROUP BY [USER].UserName` right before `ORDER BY` and `max(UserLogin.AttemptDate)` in the select?

Comment: You need to append a criteria to your left join. Typically you could join it on where a subquery returns the max datetime for a login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that each UserId has more than one match in UserLogin, you have to prioritize records for a given UserId from the UserLogin and choose the one that you want in the result set:

```
SELECT [USER].UserName , x.AttemptDate , .LogoutDate
FROM [User] 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY <PriorityCondition>) Priority
    FROM    UserLogin 
) x

ON [User].UserId = x.UserId AND x.Priority = 1
WHERE  [User].TenantId=3 
ORDER BY x.LogoutDate desc
```

Like in this example:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE (UserId INT, UserName VARCHAR(100), TenantId INT)
INSERT @User VALUES (1, 'a', 3), (2, 'b', 3)

DECLARE @UserLogin TABLE (UserId INT, UserName VARCHAR(100), AttemptDate DATETIME, LogoutDate DATETIME)
INSERT @UserLogin VALUES (1, 'a', GETDATE(), GETDATE()), 
(2, 'b', GETDATE(), GETDATE()),
(2, 'b', GETDATE(), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))


SELECT y.UserName , x.AttemptDate , x.LogoutDate
FROM @User y
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY LogoutDate DESC) Priority
    FROM    @UserLogin 
) x 
ON y.UserId = x.UserId AND x.Priority = 1
WHERE  y.TenantId=3 
ORDER BY x.LogoutDate DESC
```

Comment: Will work. Will probably be very slow. Why not just use ``top 1`` in the sub query?

Comment: Thanks Ivan but i think there is some issue with the syntax 'The multi-part identifier "x.AttemptDate" could not be bound.'

Comment: Thanks Ivan Working Fine just saw x.LogoutDate was missing in a hurry

Comment: @Sudantha To ask for help on programming details. We are not free programming labour.

Comment: @stefan - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) = 1` is no slower than `TOP 1 ORDER BY x`  If there is an appropriate index both are lightning fast.  If there is no appropriate index both require a sort.  The main difference is that the `ROW_NUMBER()` allows `n records per group` while the `TOP()` option only allows `n records`.

Comment: @stefan so why u inter-pit question goes to `programming labour` than help ? why you define like that ?

Comment: @Dems Since this is a subquery it cannot be guranteed to be optimized to the same "Lightning fast" procedure. But sure. Execution plan COULD be the same. But if its not it will be painfully slow.. I just assume that the query optimizer in sql server is stupid nowadays.

Comment: I compared query cost with Zane Bien's query, it produces different query plans, difference is around 0,008 in favor of Zane's query.

Comment: @stefan - Why do you assume SQL Server optimiser is stupid?  That the `ROW_NUMBER()` is generated in a sub-query is not a problem, I use that pattern all the time.

Comment: @Dems. Ok. In my previous attempts doing same stuff I have been given whacko execution plans. However I am not saying that it has to be "stupid". However the top cannot and will not return more than one row.

Comment: @stefan - Nor will `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`.

Comment: @Dems yes but its outside the abstract result set from the sub query.

Comment: Is there a possibility to uncheck this answer as best? For example if I delete it? Zane's query has the smallest cost and should be marked as answer.

Comment: @Ivan__83, yes it is possible to do that, however, that decision should be based on the answer that best fits the OP's needs. While mine may perform faster (albeit slight), yours has the advantage in that it is flexible and easy to adjust if the OP decided that he/she needed to retrieve say... the top *two or three logins* per user. So *performance* vs *flexibility* vs *standards adherence*?

Comment: @stefan - And the optimiser handles that perfectly fine with indexed data.  It's not like the execution plan would be "Generate all rows, then discard all but the first".  The presence of an inline view will *not* cause the optimiser to melt-down.

Comment: Well spotted, but I would like the OP to uncheck it anyway and check your's as the answer because it best fits OP's current needs, maybe the performance difference isn't that big when viewed in execution plan but I suppose it could be an issue in case of a large number of records. I tried to delete it to let the OP check new answer but it can't be done.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    a.UserName,
    c.AttemptDate,
    c.LogoutDate
FROM
    [User] a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT UserId, MAX(LogoutDate) AS maxdate
        FROM UserLogin
        GROUP BY UserId
    ) b ON a.UserId = b.UserId
LEFT JOIN
    UserLogin c ON b.UserId = c.UserId AND b.maxdate = c.LogoutDate
WHERE
    a.TenantId = 3
ORDER BY
    c.LogoutDate DESC
```

This query has the additional advantage of being DBMS-agnostic (except for the brackets around `User`), and does not rely on window-functions or external variables.

Comment: Thanks looks like this query is much faster than Ivans Sorry but i have already accepted his :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as(
SELECT [USER].UserId , max(UserLogin.LogoutDate ) [LogoutDate]
FROM [User] JOIN UserLogin 
ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId 
WHERE  [User].TenantId=3 
group by [USER].UserId 
 )
 select U.UserName,L.AttemptDate , L.LogoutDate from cte C , UserLogin L,
 [User] U
 where C.LogoutDate=L.LogoutDate
 and C.UserId=L.UserId
 and U.UserId=L.UserId
```

Comment: `JOIN` (ANSI-92) syntax ***and*** `,` syntax in one query?  Very poor practice imho.  Also, how is this actually different from Zane's query?  Answer; Zane and the OP have `LEFT JOIN` and you don't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
SELECT [USER].UserName , UserLogin.AttemptDate , MAX(UserLogin.LogoutDate) FROM [User] LEFT JOIN UserLogin  ON [User].UserId = UserLogin.UserId  WHERE  [User].TenantId=3 ORDER BY UserLogin.LogoutDate desc
```

Comment: `Column 'User.UserName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`